# Dynamodb is it possible to query all values in a column

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to work out the best method for querying all the values down a column. Should I set it as a GSI (it is currently). is it possible with a query or would I need to to do a scan?

Thanks for your help

Comment: DynamoDB is not an analytical DB. If you need it once, you can use scan, but if you need it often use other solutions (Redshift from DynamoDB Update Stream, or maintain the value sets from the update stream in Redis in ElastiCache).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do a scan if you are not filtering by key. Here is the sample code to scan the index and get all the values.

```
    List<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dynamoDBClient);
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("Music");
    Index index = table.getIndex("Secondary Index Name");

    ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> items = null;   
    ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec().withSelect(Select.SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES).withAttributesToGet("Category");

    items = index.scan(scanSpec);
    Iterator<Item> pageIterator = items.iterator();
    while (pageIterator.hasNext() ) {

        categoryList.add(pageIterator.next().getString("Category"));
    }
```